# Why Sketch don't offer 16px font by default?

Tags: fonts, sketch-app

I frequently use 16px font in UI design. But Sketch don't have this optioon in dropdown. Is there any typography lesson i can learn from this case?

Comment: Your choice wasn't very popular when the software interface was designed and tested.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Your chosen font size didn't make the cut.

Original font sizes had names such as pica, royal, agate, etc.

Later, fonts were given numerical sizes

The numbers chosen for the font sizes in the drop-down menu were chosen as common fractional parts of a base number.

The base number for British Typography was 1 inch.
Printers measure was given in points.
The conversions were set upon that relationship and rounded for convenience.

After 1 inch was established as being equal to 72 points (very roughly), the fractional multiples followed: /2=36pts., /3=24pts., /4=18pts., /5=14.5pts., /6=12pts., /7=10.2pts., /8=9pts., etc.

Type foundries sold popular sizes of their fonts and software companies trimmed their long menu choices to similar popular fractional sizes.

Similar short cuts were adopted with the change to screen pixels from points for hard-copy.